# Procedure to determine class capacity not displaying outputs

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a procedure that's supposed to determine the class sections at maximum enrollment. I have an "Enrollment" table and "Section" table. The Enrollment table has a column for "sectionID" and the section table has a column for "sectionID" and "capacity". Now the issue I'm having is that my code is not display anything at all after compiling.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE section_max AS

        CURSOR enrollment_sectionID IS
        SELECT SECTION_ID
        FROM ENROLLMENT;

        CURSOR section_sectionID IS
        SELECT SECTION_ID
        FROM SECTION;

        CURSOR section_capacity IS
        SELECT CAPACITY
        FROM SECTION;

        inc NUMBER(3,0);
        temp_enrollment_sectionID NUMBER(8,0); 
        temp_section_sectionID NUMBER(8,0);
        temp_section_capacity NUMBER(3,0);

        BEGIN
              OPEN enrollment_sectionID;
              OPEN section_sectionID;
              OPEN section_capacity;
              LOOP
                FETCH enrollment_sectionID
                INTO temp_enrollment_sectionID;
                EXIT WHEN enrollment_sectionID%NOTFOUND;
                inc := 0;
                LOOP
                      FETCH section_sectionID
                      INTO temp_section_sectionID;
                      FETCH section_capacity
                      INTO temp_section_capacity;
                      EXIT WHEN section_sectionID%NOTFOUND;

                      IF temp_enrollment_sectionID = temp_section_sectionID THEN
                    inc := inc + 1; --inc is the incrementer or counter
                    IF inc = temp_section_capacity THEN
                          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Section ' || temp_enrollment_sectionID || ' is maxed out');
                    END IF;
                      END IF;
                END LOOP; 
              END LOOP;
        END section_max;
```

The capacity column list 2 sections that are at max capacity, however, nothing is displayed after running my code

Answer (score 1):

Compiling - nothing should show except for maybe compilation status - success, errors, or warnings.

Now executing is a different matter.

In Oracle SQL Developer, in order to see DBMS OUTPUT, you need to enable it first.

In your SQL Worksheet, run this

```
set serveroutput on
```

Then exec your procedure. You'll see the DBMS OUTPUT in the Script Output panel

[image]

Or, open the DBMS Output panel on the View menu. Add your connection, then run your code. The output will show in the new panel in your desktop.

[image]

Comment: thanks, solved my issue of getting it to display. However, is there a way to shorten this code up or make it more efficient?

Comment: Shorten/tune your code? That would be a brand new question.